# How to predict Label of an email using a trained NB Classifier in sklearn?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, naivebayes

I have created a Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier on a email (spam/not spam) dataset and was able to run it successfully. I vectorized the data, divided in it train and test sets and then calculated the accuracy, all the features that are present in the sklearn-Gaussian Naive Bayes classifier.

Now I want to be able to use this classifier to predict "labels" for new emails - whether they are by spam or not.
For example say I have an email. I want to feed it to my classifier and get the prediction as to whether it is a spam or not. How can I achieve this? Please Help.

Code for classifier file.

```js
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys
from time import time
import logging

# Display progress logs on stdout
logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG, format = '%(asctime)s %(message)s')

sys.path.append("../DatasetProcessing/")
from vectorize_split_dataset import preprocess

### features_train and features_test are the features
for the training and testing datasets, respectively### labels_train and labels_test are the corresponding item labels
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = preprocess()

#########################################################
from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB
clf = GaussianNB()
t0 = time()
clf.fit(features_train, labels_train)
pred = clf.predict(features_test)
print("training time:", round(time() - t0, 3), "s")
print(clf.score(features_test, labels_test))

## Printing Metrics
for Training and Testing
print("No. of Testing Features:" + str(len(features_test)))
print("No. of Testing Features Label:" + str(len(labels_test)))
print("No. of Training Features:" + str(len(features_train)))
print("No. of Training Features Label:" + str(len(labels_train)))
print("No. of Predicted Features:" + str(len(pred)))

## Calculating Classifier Performance
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = labels_test
y_pred = pred
labels = ['0', '1']
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names = target_names, labels = labels))

# How to predict label of a new text
new_text = "You won a lottery at UK lottery commission. Reply to claim it"
```

Code for Vectorization

```js
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import pickle
import numpy
numpy.random.seed(42)

path = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

### The words(features) and label_data(labels), already largely processed.###These files should have been created beforehand
feature_data_file = path + "./createdDataset/dataSet.pkl"
label_data_file = path + "./createdDataset/dataLabel.pkl"

feature_data = pickle.load(open(feature_data_file, "rb"))
label_data = pickle.load(open(label_data_file, "rb"))

### test_size is the percentage of events assigned to the test set(the### remainder go into training)### feature matrices changed to dense representations
for compatibility with### classifier functions in versions 0.15.2 and earlier
from sklearn import cross_validation
features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test = cross_validation.train_test_split(feature_data, label_data, test_size = 0.1, random_state = 42)

from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
vectorizer = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf = True, max_df = 0.5, stop_words = 'english')
features_train = vectorizer.fit_transform(features_train)
features_test = vectorizer.transform(features_test)#.toarray()

## feature selection to reduce dimensionality
from sklearn.feature_selection import SelectPercentile, f_classif
selector = SelectPercentile(f_classif, percentile = 5)
selector.fit(features_train, labels_train)
features_train_transformed_reduced = selector.transform(features_train).toarray()
features_test_transformed_reduced = selector.transform(features_test).toarray()

features_train = features_train_transformed_reduced
features_test = features_test_transformed_reduced

def preprocess():
  return features_train, features_test, labels_train, labels_test
```

Code for dataset generation

```js
#!/usr/bin/python

import os
import pickle
import re
import sys

# sys.path.append("../tools/")


""
"
    Starter code to process the texts of accuate and inaccurate category to extract
    the features and get the documents ready for classification.

    The list of all the texts from accurate category are in the accurate_files list
    likewise for texts of inaccurate category are in (inaccurate_files)

    The data is stored in lists and packed away in pickle files at the end.
"
""


accurate_files = open("./rawDatasetLocation/accurateFiles.txt", "r")
inaccurate_files = open("./rawDatasetLocation/inaccurateFiles.txt", "r")

label_data = []
feature_data = []

### temp_counter is a way to speed up the development--there are### thousands of lines of accurate and inaccurate text, so running over all of them### can take a long time### temp_counter helps you only look at the first 200 lines in the list so you### can iterate your modifications quicker
temp_counter = 0


for name, from_text in [("accurate", accurate_files), ("inaccurate", inaccurate_files)]:
  for path in from_text: ###only look at first 200 texts when developing### once everything is working, remove this line to run over full dataset
temp_counter = 1
if temp_counter < 200:
  path = os.path.join('..', path[: -1])
print(path)
text = open(path, "r")
line = text.readline()
while line: ###use a
function parseOutText to extract the text from the opened text# stem_text = parseOutText(text)
stem_text = text.readline().strip()
print(stem_text)### use str.replace() to remove any instances of the words# stem_text = stem_text.replace("germani", "")### append the text to feature_data
feature_data.append(stem_text)### append a 0 to label_data
if text is from Sara, and 1
if text is from Chris
if (name == "accurate"):
  label_data.append("0")
elif(name == "inaccurate"):
  label_data.append("1")

line = text.readline()

text.close()

print("texts processed")
accurate_files.close()
inaccurate_files.close()

pickle.dump(feature_data, open("./createdDataset/dataSet.pkl", "wb"))
pickle.dump(label_data, open("./createdDataset/dataLabel.pkl", "wb"))
```

Also I want to know whether i can incrementally train the classifier meaning thereby that retrain a created model with newer data for refining the model over time?

I would be really glad if someone can help me out with this. I am really stuck at this point.

Comment: As you have already done the train_test split on a already tagged set and then calculating the accuracy. For the new Test data, you would have to load your new Test Data set into the features_test variable. For the prediction you can do two things, either fit_transform your NB everytime you have a new Test data, or save the NB model (use sklearn.externals.joblib.dump/load, and for each new test set, load your model and use predict. You can incrementally train the classifier, but the old classifier would have to be replaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using your model to predict labels of emails in your test set. This is what `pred = clf.predict(features_test)` does. If you want to see these labels, do `print pred`.

But perhaps you what to know how you can predict labels for emails that you discover in the future and that are not currently in your test set? If so, you can think of your new email(s) as a new test set. As with your previous test set, you will need to run several key processing steps on the data:

1) The first thing you need to do is to generate features for your new email data. The feature generation step is not included in your code above, but will need to occur.

2) You are using a Tfidf vectorizer, which converts a collection of documents to a matrix of Tfidf features based upon term frequency and inverse document frequency. You need to put your new email test feature data through the vectorizer that you fit on your training data.

3) Then your new email test feature data will need to go through dimensionality reduction using the same `selector` that you fit on your training data.

4) Finally, run predict on your new test data. Use `print pred` if you want to view the new label(s).

To respond to your final question about iteratively re-training your model, yes you definitely can do this. It's just a matter of selecting a frequency, producing a script that expands your data set with incoming data, then re-running all steps from there, from pre-processing to Tfidf vectorization, to dimensionality reduction, to fitting, and prediction.

Comment: Thanks for the solution Jason. Yeah that's exactly what I was trying to ask. How to generate features for the new email data. That's where I was stuck. Can you please elaborate a bit on that point? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi @user2168281, all of the feature engineering steps occur outside the code you posted above, so it's impossible to say. You are pulling your feature data in here `feature_data_file = path + "./createdDataset/dataSet.pkl"` and here `feature_data = pickle.load(open(feature_data_file, "rb"))`. If you did not do the feature engineering yourself, you'll need to at least track down the source code to see what the features are and how they were built so that you can re-do on your end for new data. Sorry I can't help more. If you find the source code for feature generation, let us know.

Comment: I should say that it is possible that the feature data is actually just the email text itself, and that it is the Tfidf vectorizer that turns this raw email text data into features. If that is the case, then feature generation for your new email data will occur in the Tfidf step mentioned above. But I can't say for sure because we don't have visibility on what `features_data` looks like once it has been importer in this step `feature_data = pickle.load(open(feature_data_file, "rb"))`.

Comment: Hi Jason. I have updated the question with dataset creation logic. Herein the files contain simple text Strings.

Comment: This code pre-processes the texts in several ways -- for example, by running `strip` and `replace` on the texts. You need to make sure that your new emails are in same format as the texts being read in by `open("./rawDatasetLocation/accurateFiles.txt", "r")`. Make sure they are `.txt` files and that they have the same header and body layout. From there, you can run new txt file through the processing code, starting with `for name, from_text in` and ending with `feature_data.append(stem_text)`.

Comment: You won't need the last part which creates labels, though feel free to include this if you do actually know the new true labels. Finally, dump the new feature (and possibly new label) data into pickle with the same last step `pickle.dump(feature_data, open("./createdDataset/dataSet-new.pkl", "wb"))`. Now you have the same type of input as your original training and test data, which you can use to chug through the steps in the previous parts of your post (e.g., Tfidf, selector...).

Comment: Hi, Thanks Jason. It works for me. Thanks a lot for the right nudge :)